# opening oracle application in a browser

Tags: selenium, oracleapplications, oracle-apps

Is it possible to open oracle applications inside a browser itself instead of it opening a separate window? because if this is done than we can automate oracle applications using selenium. I'm using oracle applications 11.5 .

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

We cannot open the Oracle Forms in browser. From Oracle R12, many of the Oracle Forms are moved to Oracle pages ( OAF and ADF ).

Dataload can still automate the Oracle Forms in both 11i and R12. You can give it a try.